# Inserindo Imagem no Banco de Dados com Java Web

Tags: java, primefaces, aplicação-web, upload, imagem

Estou com dificuldades em inserir uma imagem em banco de dados. Tenho já um método de salvar e estou incluindo um campo de foto, mas não estou sabendo como implementar para fazer o upload da imagem.

Quem puder me ajudar, serei grato.

Segue abaixo os codigos:

```java
package com.br.mvsistemasjavaweb.controler.usuarios;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.br.mvsistemasjavaweb.controler.departamento.Departamentos;
import com.br.mvsistemasjavaweb.model.usuarios.TipoUsuarios;
import com.br.mvsistemasjavaweb.model.usuarios.Usuario;
import com.br.mvsistemasjavaweb.model.usuarios.UsuarioAtivo;
import com.br.mvsistemasjavaweb.repository.usuarios.Usuarios;
import com.br.mvsistemasjavaweb.service.usuarios.CadastroUsuariosService;
import com.br.mvsistemasjavaweb.util.FacesMessages;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UsuariosBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Usuarios usuarios;

    @Inject
    private CadastroUsuariosService cadastroUsuarios;

    @Inject
    private FacesMessages mensagens;

    private List<Usuario> todosUsuarios;

    private Usuario usuarioEdicao = new Usuario();

    private Usuario usuarioSelecionado;

    private Departamentos departamento;

    private Part foto;

    public void salvarUsuarios() throws IOException {
        // Linha para inserção da imagem
        this.usuarioEdicao.setFoto(IOUtils.toByteArray(this.foto.getInputStream()));
        this.cadastroUsuarios.salvar(usuarioEdicao);
        this.usuarioEdicao = new Usuario();
        this.consultar();
        mensagens.info("Usuario Salvo com Sucesso!");
    }

// ... Restante do código
```

Componente da view que insere a foto:

```jsp
                <p:outputLabel value="Foto de Perfil" />
                <p:fileUpload value="#{usuariosBean.foto}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>
```

Comment: Em geral, não é uma boa pratica armazenar fotos em banco de dados, mas como o problema é no upload, poderia informar como esta declarando seu form? E a versão de Servlet esta usando?

Comment: O array de bytes que chega no servidor está correto ou não?

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo JSF e PrimeFaces, lá no Form eu coloquei a seguinte instrução: enctype="multipart/form-data". Agora o erro é outro, ele esta apresentando: #{usuariosBean.salvarUsuarios}: java.lang.NullPointerException nesse EL que é chamado no metodo acima, a IDE mostra que o nullPointer é na seguinte linha: this.usuarioEdicao.setFoto(IOUtils.toByteArray(this.foto.getInputStream())); Quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua classe UsuariosBean deve estar anotada com @SessionScoped, é uma restrição do fileUpload do prime. Uma "alternativa" para não manter essa classe na sessão é criar um outro ManagedBean só para fazer o upload. No framework que trabalho temos um exemplo disso:  https://github.com/demoiselle/laboratory/blob/master/estacionamento/v240/src/main/java/br/gov/serpro/lab/estacionamento/view/ClienteEditMB.java

Comment: Amigo Saito, tem como eu lhe enviar o codigo fonte pra ver se tem como me ajudar??? Fiz a anotação mas esta apresentando outro erro...

Comment: Pode sim. Se pudesse colocar isso num repositório como o https://bitbucket.org (permite repositórios privados) ou https://github.com  fica mais fácil de colaborar. O meu email é: emerson.saito no gmail.